# How to debug performance of a powershell cmdlet

Tags: c#, powershell

I am executing a PowerShell cmdlet - `Get-VmHardDiskDrive <VMName>` from a C# based service running on the Hyper-V host. That particular cmdlet takes a lot of time to execute. But when I run the same command in a fresh instance of PowerShell console on the host it is executing very fast. I have logged the command and cross checked and I use the same logged command on the PowerShell console window as well. Also, I have checked the eventviewer for any errors in the service but I see nothing.

So my questions are:

1. Any suggestions on what might be wrong?
2. Any way to debug a Windows PowerShell cmdlet to see what is taking time?
3. Any steps that I can try out?
4. Can I use something else instead of `Get-VmHardDiskDrive` which gives me similar information?

Note: The PowerShell script is being executed in an async manner from the service.

Comment: PowerShell.exe is a .NET application. So literally you can use a .NET profiler to analyze the process. There are also other PowerShell related profiling approaches, http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2011/11/15/advanced-script-profiling/

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the async execution (try to execute synchronously) or the thread priority the service is running with.

Comment: Please show us the [tag:c#] code used to invoke the cmdlet